# Lift - Setting it up

Tags: scala, lift, sbt

Today I started with scala and lift and I am currently reading though the docs. I managed to get it started with the help of the cookbook.

However I want to read though some bigger examples, especially this example because it uses mongodb + authentication https://github.com/eltimn/lift-mongo.g8/tree/master/src/main/g8

I didn't use g8 nor cs because I had some errors with cs and I was to lazy to investigate them.

So I just cloned the repo to my hard drive. I think that is what g8 is doing.

So some files are missing, I added them

- sbt
- sbt.bat (I am using windows)
- sbt-launch.jar

But I get the following errors:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#sbt-closure;0.1.3: not found
[warn]  :: com.github.siasia#xsbt-web-plugin_2.9.1;0.11.2
ound
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I tried to fix the sbt-closure but I could not find it in with the maven search

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Csbt-closure

the plugins.sbt looks like this

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases",
  new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(
    Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("org.scala-sbt" % "sbt-closure" % "0.1.3")

addSbtPlugin("me.lessis" % "less-sbt" % "0.1.10")

libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion(v => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % (v+"-0.2.11.1"))
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SBT plugins need to be re-published for each new version of SBT.  My guess is that the template you downloaded was based on an older version of SBT (0.11 maybe?) and that the versions of the plugins you are referencing haven't been published for the latest SBT (0.12).  You could try to find an older version of SBT to download, but you're probably better off either getting g8/conscript working, or using one of these templates: https://github.com/lift/lift_24_sbt.

Comment: The template is actually for sbt 0.12 and sbt-closure 0.1.3 is available for sbt 0.12 only. I think the actual problem is he tried to run it with sbt 0.11.